# What is the difference between Application Insights on VS Online or Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-application-insights

I added Application Insights on Visual Studio Online. Also I have a website running on Azure which have a Application Insights on Azure. Now I am receiving page view info in VS Online, and telemetry info in Azure. How can I join them together? What is the difference?

**Update:**

[Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc5937d5-1cd9-4bf1-aca0-780e4606e233/what-is-the-difference-between-application-insights-on-vs-online-or-azure?forum=ApplicationInsights) is the complete answer.

Comment: The one on Azure is the new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked it on MSDN Forum and got the complete answer.
[Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc5937d5-1cd9-4bf1-aca0-780e4606e233/what-is-the-difference-between-application-insights-on-vs-online-or-azure?forum=ApplicationInsights) it is.

> Application Insights for VSO is an older version of Application Insights. At this point all new Application Insights account are created in Azure portal and going forward Application Insights for VSO will not be supported.
>
> From what you described you are getting your telemetry in Azure portal  (by telemetry I am assuming your page request data), but your page views are coming to VSO.  The reason is that there's JavaScript on your website that is sending data to your VSO account. My suggestion was to instead insert JavaScript snippet which would be sending it to your Azure account, so you can view all your telemetry data there.

Comment: In general it's good to include the relevant part from a link in case the link goes down or the resource moves.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the script in your web pages. It's probably in a master page like Views\Shared_Layout. You'll find it in the  section. Delete the old one and insert the new one.

You get the new one by going to App Insights - click Quick Start and look under the second step, where it says "Get the script..."

See http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-insights-web-track-usage/